# Detect Setting from Visual Studio Custom Extension

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2019, visual-studio-extensions

I am updating an existing Visual Studio extension to be compatible with Visual Studio 2019. This extension allows devs to create a custom project type. When users click Visual Studio's "Create" button to create a new project of this custom type, the extension shows a custom form to retrieve certain info from the dev before the extension creates the project. This is accomplished from within a Wizard class library specified in the vstemplate of my extension:

```
<WizardExtension>
    <Assembly>...Wizard, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b5b18240577bb6e8</Assembly>    
    <FullClassName>...Wizard.Logic.Wizard</FullClassName>
</WizardExtension>
```

My question is this:

- Is there a way to detect whether or not the **Place solution and project in the same directory** checkbox shown below is checked from within the `Wizard` class of my extension ?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way to detect whether or not the Place solution and project
>   in the same directory checkbox shown below is checked from within the
>   Wizard class of my extension ?

I'm afraid the answer is negative. `VS2019 SDK` doesn't have the api to know if `Place solution and project in the same directory` is checked or not. This checkbox is not a valid setting for Solution or even Project.

Assuming your template has two forms when creating a template(Similar to `asp.net` web project). `Form1` is the normal one from VS IDE while the `Form2` is your custom one from `Wizard`, the solution file and related project folder, hidden `.vs` folder won't be created until you click the **final** **Create** button. So I think the info about `Place solution and project in the same directory` is stored in temp cache before the project is finally created. And this is hard to access in your Wizard Class.

So I think for now, what you want is not supported behavior...

Comment: You are correct about my template having two forms when creating a template, the VS IDE form followed by the custom form in my Wizard. If their is not an official api to give me the checkbox information I was hoping I could figure out an alternate way to detect the checkbox status even if it's a bit hackish, but I haven't been able to come up with anything yet.

Comment: I also tried to check if there's any alternative way, but i found when we choose the checkbox in form1 or even form2, there's no content(even the .vs folder) created in solution folder. So I think when we're in form2, the info about if we've checked the box is stored in temp cache somewhere but not the solution itself... Which means it's hard to find the info we want :-(